# Golang SWIG Example 2: slice bounds out of range panic

Tags: go, int, size, swig

Im currently working myself through the [SWIG Go examples](https://github.com/swig/swig/tree/master/Examples/go) and I`m having a problem on the second example "[constants](https://github.com/swig/swig/tree/master/Examples/go/constants)"

For some reason im getting a slice bounds out of range panic but only if I specify `32` as the argument for the `-intgosize` paramter in the swig call.

If I run swig with `swig -go -intgosize 64 example.i` everything works fine

The `example.i` swig file looks as follows

```
/* File : example.i */
%module example

/* A few preprocessor macros */

#define    ICONST      42
#define    FCONST      2.1828
#define    CCONST      'x'
#define    CCONST2     '\n'
#define    SCONST      "Hello World"
#define    SCONST2     "\"Hello World\""

/* This should work just fine */
#define    EXPR        ICONST + 3*(FCONST)

/* This shouldn't do anything */
#define    EXTERN      extern

/* Neither should this (BAR isn't defined) */
#define    FOO         (ICONST + BAR)

/* The following directives also produce constants */

%constant int iconst = 37;
%constant double fconst = 3.14;
```

Judging from the output i get when running swig with the 32 argument I assumed the panic is caused by the `SCONST2` and after commenting out the `#define SCONST2` line the panic was gone.

The output with `SCONST2` looks like this:

```
panic: runtime error: slice bounds out of range [:824633720845] with length 2147483647

goroutine 1 [running]:
swigtest/02_constants.swigCopyString(0x1056760, 0xc00000000d, 0xc000107ef0, 0xc000107ef8)
        C:/Users/visfgp/go/personal_code/src/swigtest/02_constants/example.go:64 +0xb0
swigtest/02_constants._swig_getSCONST2(0x50230a, 0xc00003e1e0)
        C:/Users/visfgp/go/personal_code/src/swigtest/02_constants/example.go:97 +0x4a
swigtest/02_constants.init()
        C:/Users/visfgp/go/personal_code/src/swigtest/02_constants/example.go:101 +0x38
```

My question is way is this panic thrown by this string in particular, why is it not thrown by the `SCONST` string and what does it have to do with the size of go ints?

Comment: 2147483647 is the Mac value for an int32. 824633720845 clearly exceeds that.

Answer (score 0):

When you define a int32 variable it's range is `-2147483648` to `2147483647`. Perhaps your variable is exceding this range `[:824633720845]`. You should use int64 in this case!

Comment: I mean I know the range of an int32. I was wondering how and why the string `"\"Hello World\""` exceeds that range while `"Hello World"` or even longer strings like `"the brown fox jumps over the lazy dog"` do not.